# on click, check if div is open, if false - open using .show, if true do nothing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, show-hide

I'm using jquery `.show` to open a `div`. I've got it working fine but I'm having a bit of trouble working out how to get it to check if the `div`'s already open. If it is, I don't want it to repeat the `.show` function. What's the best way to do this?

What I'm using at the moment is (jquery + jquery ui)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.content').hide(); 

$(".open").click(function () {
  $(".content").show("slide", { direction: "up" },1200);
});

$(".close").click(function () {
  $(".content").hide("slide", { direction: "up" },1200);
});

});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [:visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [:hidden selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $(".open").click(function () {
        $(".content:hidden").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1200);
    });
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".content:visible").hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1200);
    });
});
```

Also see [my example](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($(".content").is(":visible") {
    // it is showing already
} ...
```

You might also look at http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

## ¡¡¡FUN EXAMPLES HERE!!!